# The difference between 路 and 道?

Tags: word-choice

I feel that a very important difference could possibly be highlighted here.  I am not entirely sure.

For one, I do see the difference between the two with a grand scale.
With that said, I also under stand the importance of 路, especially when with the word 露. Hailing from a City of Rain, I had the question come to light.

Does this word have a con notation strictly on the MDBG site?
It also includes the definition of betray, is that then in the eye of the be holder?

路  would seem to stem from foot, mouth and each/every .  Then does an implication exist that could be misused?

Is 路 then a step on the way to 道 through proper motions?

Edit:  The reason I came across this was because I was re minded of a girl with whom I played League with at a time. haha.  That was coupled with the fact that 露露 is also an almond milk, which I wrote along the line of yesterday.

The original question stemmed from the line following:  "锏是一种中国传统古代兵器之一。"  Intrigued with the usage of 之一，　I had wanted to build a sentence using both the Chinese almond milk, and this one.

Comment: see more dictionaries, esp. bkrs, jukuu, also search web：e.g. (most detailed) https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/279851544.html  道与路有什么区别？  https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/17694680.html 道和路的区别？https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/82832830.html 道与路有什么区别

Comment: I will read it in the future, my literacy competence is not level with article scope.

Comment: Generally when they are used for road, width of 道 > 路.    路 can be used for all road, but 道 used for wide road only.

Comment: That is fair, my scope has also widened.  Originally, my choice of word was going to be par before level.  I learned of the etymological roots of the word 'imperative'.  Interested with 'imperare' in particular, I continue research.  The etymological roots of different parts of that word make a lot of sense to this one path.  When I decide to return to base, I realize that I was along the same lines all along.  Par are means to make ready.

Comment: As a plus, the one sentence preceding this as my previous comment is another thing that I mentioned on this site.  The importance of diction in the English language!  That last sentence can have a certain array of meanings!

Comment: 小道, 小径, 小路: path; 路: road; 街: street, 大道: avenue, boulevard. These nouns describe different kinds of road. 道路: General name for all paths, roads, streets, avenues, boulevards. The characters 路, 街, 大道 are used as the suffix of road names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of character formation may not be always correct. E.g., 露 used to have that meaning (well before the 12th century AD), but now it means "water drops (on/from plants)".

In general, 道 is a bit more abstract than 路, silimar to "path" and "road" in English. 路 often means the road you're going on, and 道 can have the meaning of "method/approach".

> – 你从哪条路过来的？ Which road did you come from?
> – 我从那条小道过来的。 I came from that small path.

Usually they are interchangeable, but sometimes...

> 条条大路通罗马。 (not 大道)
> All roads lead to Rome. (not "path")
>
> (road name) XX大道 (Blah Boulevard)
> XX大路？ (Blah <s>Big Road</s>)

道 can also mean a social subject,

> 混白道，混黑道 (do business and run gangs)
> <s>白路/黑路</s> (<s>white road and black road</s>)